# How can I get the root/parent class of an object?

Tags: python

How can I check the root/parent class of an object? e.g

```
from PIL import Image as im
x = im.open('test.png')

type(x)
Out[]: PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile

#pseudocode:
isinstance_parent(x, PIL)
Out[]: True
```

I have a list which contains PIL image objects of different types (PNG, JPEG etc.). I want to be able to check which are PIL image objects so I can close them later in the script (so it will allow me to delete them).

I've searched quite a bit but couldn't make any answers work for me. Most point to using some variance of isinstance(object, type) but that requires being very specific:

```
isinstance(x, PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile)
Out[]: True
```

But the images could be one of many types JPG, GIF, PNG etc. I'd ideally like just to be able to see if belongs to the PIL class.

I've thought of hacky ways to do it... just make a list of every image it could be and see how PIL classifies them.

Or something like this:

```
str(type(x))
Out[80]: "<class 'PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile'>"

if str(type(x)).split()[1].startswith('\'PIL'):
    print('It is an image')
```

But I feel like there should be a more pythonic way that I'm missing right?

Cheers

Comment: Would `isinstance(x, PIL.Image.Image)` work for you?

Comment: Lol... I feel like someone who's been pulling every which way at a door to open it and you just pointed at the "PUSH" sign. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

PIL images inherit from [`PIL.Image.Image`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image), so you can simply do the test as:

```
if isinstance(x, PIL.Image.Image):
    pass  # do stuff
```

Comment: Lovely. Cheers. Upvote because it solves my issue. I'll leave the accepted answer open for a while since it doesn't exactly solve what was asked, just in case an answer comes for that later (for the benefit of future people searching).

Comment: That's legit. Just bear in mind that in Python, everybody inherits from [`object`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#object), so I'm not sure about your exact question...